# cannot resolve method create 'com.google.common.net.MediaType,java.lang.String)

Tags: java, android, json, okhttp

I want to send a device to device Firebase notification using OkHttp 3, but am getting the following error when posting the JSON:

```
cannot resolve method create 'com.google.common.net.MediaType,java.lang.String)
```

Here is my code:

```
final String legacyServerKey = "";
final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
JSONObject dataJson = new JSONObject();
dataJson.put("body", "Hi this is sent from device to device");
dataJson.put("title", "dummy title");
json.put("notification", dataJson);
json.put("to", reg_token);

RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, json.toString());
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .header("Authorization", "key=" + legacyServerKey)
        .url("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
        .post(body)
        .build();

try {
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    String finalResponse = response.body().string();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you imported `com.google.common.net.MediaType`. You need `okhttp3.MediaType`